# Inheritance in Angular: Component or Normal Class?

Tags: angular, components

There are a couple of components which use some same methods. I've decided to make a class, extract the sharing methods and put them into the class. Now the components which want to use the methods are extending the class and it works fine. Here comes the question. I've come to learn that Angular supports Component inheritance as well so at this point, I'm wondering if component inheritance is better over just normal class inheritance. What's confusing me is that the possible parent component won't be used itself so I don't see any point to make it as a component and that's why I've implemented it as a normal class. Any insight would be impressed!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you exactly mean by component inheritance? Using a base class which also is a component? Of course you can do it, however none of the related metadata in the decorator is relevant when extending said base class, so unless you're actually using that class as a component itself, there's no need for making it a component, if that makes sense.

Comment: As I described above, I've noticed some components have same "view-related methods" so I wanted to extract them into a class and make components use them after importing the class. And since the methods are view-related, I was thinking about making the class as component but I will never use it as a component itself, I guess I will go with the normal class base.